# How to delete record from table which is not binded to gridview using rowdeleting event?

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, rowdeleting

I have one webpage developed in C# asp.net. Here, I have gridview which is binded to my table1. 
UserDetails columns are id, userID, user name 
I have another DashbaordData having columns - data1, data2, and createdby.

here input data of createdby column from DashbardData and userID from userDetails are the same.

I want to delete record from DashbardData , from the row deleting event of gridview (which is binded to userDetails) on the where condition of DashbardData .createdby=userDetails.userID.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                Label id = (Label)row.FindControl("lblRecordID");
                Label userID = (Label)row.FindControl("lbluserID");

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conDB);
            OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand();

            cmd1.CommandText = "delete* from DashboardData where Createdby =" + userID.Text + "";
            cmd1.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
             con.Close();
```

Here in code, i am getting the userID value from userdetails table which is binded to gridview, and passing that userID to delete query to delete record from Dashbaordata table.

In debug i see that query is correct, it is picking up the correct value but when it execute cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); nothing happnes. it goes to catch section and give error as parameters not found.

I have doubt whether we can do like this- deleting another table record using row deleting event of some different table gridview ?

could you please help me how I can do it.

Comment: what you tried? simply put your code for clear understanding